# Spring security default form login page failing when antmatcher defined

Tags: java, spring-security

I am having an issue with Spring 5 form based authentication. This is only an example at this point as I am trying to isolate the issue I'm having.  My plan is to include this configuration in a larger project with multiple configurations.  The below code (which can be found anywhere) works as expected:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
  {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("password")).roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and().csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

and following code does not work after adding antmatcher:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
  {
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder)
        .withUser("user").password(passwordEncoder.encode("password")).roles("USER");
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
  {
    http.antMatcher("/test/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .and().csrf().disable();
  }
}
```

Notice that I've only added an antmatcher to this config.  I only want the config to apply to /test/**.  And, in this case, I'm not doing anything custom with regards to the form login and would like to get Spring default form.  Of course in a real application I would not use the default but this is only for example purposes.  My first config displays the default internal Spring form correctly when I GET the following URL: http://localhost:8080/webapp/test/anything. And I can authenticate successfully.  For the second configuration I get 404 errors when issuing the same URL.

Spring security does in fact try to redirect to: http://localhost:8080/webapp/login however, the url does not exist.  I did try the following change:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.antMatcher("/test/**").authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and().formLogin().permitAll().loginPage("/test/login").loginProcessingUrl("/test/login")
            .and().logout().logoutUrl("/test/logout").invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/");
}
```

This did not work either.  I made several attempts, but have not been successful.  Is it possible that the default form behavior is disabled when an antmatcher is defined?

Comment: You can't apply spring security filters only for specific paths but you can apply a permitAll strategy to all your endpoints except the one that you want to securize. I'm not sure for the following code, but it will look like: `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll().antMatchers("/test/**").authenticated().and().formLogin().and().csrf().disable();`

Comment: This did not work because permitAll is assigned to all URL patterns and comes before the secured url /test/**.  I did try it and there was no redirect to a login page.

Comment: So maybe you have to "permitAll" a kind of endpoints whitelist. Sorry I've never implemented a spring security solution going in this way (all authorized except one path/subpath)

Answer (score 2):

This is ideal solution for your requirement

```java
@Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
 {
    http
        .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/test/**", "/customLoginPage", "/logout").and()
        .authorizeRequests()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
        .loginPage("/customLoginPage") //If you don't  configure default is "/login"
        .usernameParameter("userName").passwordParameter("password") //In case of custom form parameters
        .defaultSuccessUrl("/app/user/dashboard") //If you don't  configure default is "/"
        .failureUrl("/login?error=true") //If you don't  configure default is "/login?error"
        .and().csrf().disable();
 }
```

Let me explain Some cases how spring security deals with

**Case 1:**

```
http.authorizeRequests()
```

is equals to

```
http.antMatcher("/**").authorizeRequests()
```

A proxy filter will be defined and url-pattern for that filter will be `"/**"`. With this type of configuration there will be no problem as it is a wild card. But in some cases we don't want to define wild card `"/**"` then we should configure requestMatchers correctly otherwise we will end up in lot of unguessable problems.

**Case 2:**

```
http.antMatcher("/test/**").authorizeRequests()
```

Here proxy filter will be added with URL pattern `"/test/**"` and requests with /login and /logout can't pass through the added filter. To overcome this .requestMatchers() should be used as given below

```
http
   .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/test/**", "/customLoginPage", "/logout")
   .and().authorizeRequests()
```

This means filter with filter mapping as given below

```xml
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>/test/**</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/customLoginPage</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/logout</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can try out some of basic examples(Working) [from my github repository](https://github.com/nlpraveennl/springsecurity)

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, the following is working for me.  Only showing the configure method:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http.antMatcher("/test/**")
        .authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/test/login").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/test/logout").permitAll()
        .anyRequest().authenticated()
        .and()
        .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login.jsp").permitAll()
            .loginProcessingUrl("/test/login").permitAll()
            .failureUrl("/login.jsp?error=yes")
        .and()
        .logout().permitAll().logoutUrl("/test/logout").permitAll()
        .and().csrf().disable();
}
```

I did need to create my own login form (login.jsp), however the processing of the login form (the POST) is handled by Spring default processing.  Really, that was the important piece.  Another key point to make is that the login form POST needs to point to /webapp/test/login.  I suppose that the Spring configuration needs these additional "tips" in order to trigger the default form processing in cases where the antMatcher call must be present.